# Netlify form is not hidden on the web

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify

I 've created a netlify contact form and I followed step by step points from here: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/

I've added this to the index.html file as they want:
`<form name="contact" netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" hidden>`

Everything is fine when I deploy a web and the contact form does work but the contact form from public index.html is also on the web. I see 2 forms instead of only one. Why is not hidden like is asked to be?

The console is clear.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<form name="contact-form" netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What is the `hidden` attribute supposed to be? Is that something that Netlify provides support for?